# Android including an xml layout to activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I've an `activity.java` file in which my `setContentView(R.layout.x);` Now,I've an `y.xml` in which I've an `Linear Layout`,I've to attach an `onclick()` method to my view.
Attaching `onclick()` has to be in my `activity.java` file, How do I include `y.xml`.

I tried this,

```
1.     layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.y);
       eView = (EditText)layout. findViewById(R.id.editview);

2.      eView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editview);
```

but both gives my `null pointer exception`, How do I include my `editText`

**Update**

```
final LayoutInflater lyInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        showLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) lyInflater.inflate(R.layout.y, null);
         showView = (EditView) showLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

Comment: use [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Comment: @Bishan:In general, how do I include a view to my activity.I should always do it using inflater or I can do using my above 1 (or) 2.

Comment: @Bishan:Let em know,If I am not clear, will try to explain clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inflation as shown below:

```
final LayoutInflater lyInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout yLayout = (LinearLayout) lyInflater .inflate(
                R.layout.y, null);
eView = (EditText)yLayout.findViewById(R.id.editview);
```

So you won't get exception anymore. Hope it helps.

Comment: In general, how do I include a view to my activity.I should always do it using inflater or I can do using my above 1 (or) 2.

Comment: @ram, then you have option to use include tag only.

Answer (score 0):

`LayoutInflater` is used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding View objects.in other words, it takes as input a XML file and builds the View objects from it.

in your scenario, you have to use `LayoutInflater`. read this [article](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com/2012/06/android-layoutinflater-turorial.html).

Comment: :I used Shreya shah answer both your and his seems to be same but I get null pointer exception on this too.

Comment: from which code snippet get the null pointer exception ? post code snippet that gives exception.

Answer (score 0):

Ram.
  If you want to include `y` xml file into your `x` xml file then follw this steps.

I am assuming that you want to include `Linear Layout` into your `Activity` on click  of `onclick()` method of the button or whatever, then add the `Linear Layout` into your `x` xml file and add the `android:visibility="gone"` so at begin you can not show the linearlayout.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/history_value_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >    <<<<<<<<<<<   HERE

 ----------------------------
 -----------------------------
 </LinearLayout>
```

Now, From the java class make it visible when needed, in your case into `onclick` method.
Like...

```
linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   // linear is the object of your Linearlayout
```

If any prob then ask me.

Good Luck.

Comment: :Nope, I want to include a view in linear layout then add onclick to that view.

Comment: then add the `android:visibility="gone" ` property for that view and follow above steps for that view.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, your Activity uses `x.xml`, and you also want to include another layout that is defined in `y.xml`.

You can do so using the `<merge>` or `<include>` tags, [as described in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html).

Alternately, you can use a [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) to conditionally inflate another layout in a given place in a layout.  For example, you can include a `ViewStub` tag in `x.xml`, and inflate `y.xml` in the same spot in the view hierarchy. Then, you may attach any click listeners you need (by using `findViewById()`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) method of ViewGroup.

```
addView(layout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```